# how to prevent the overwriting in arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, global-variables

i am thinking to short out the problem of global variable. i thinking a method but i am messing up with this but to connect the chains of question i want a function that prevents any one to overwrite on the present index of array

```
window.abc[0] = "first";
```

now after writing many lines of code i mistakably write the same code but with different value such as:

```
window.abc[0] = "second";
```

then that function should come and put `second` on the index 1 that is `second` should be put in `window.abc[1]`.

Thanks.

Comment: Try using `window.abc.push("first")` instead of assigning to indices.

Comment: This is also the exact reason why you should usually avoid using global variables. Difficult to know your use case from this example but if you intend these to be different things maybe limit their scope to specific functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the "push" method the array index will automatically increase  :)

Kevin